# How to get homepage div container of wordpress website to display full width?

Tags: css

I'm looking to have the home page main content section full width 100% and all other pages with sidebar at 75%.

I have a homepage template set up, what can I add to the homepage template 
(page-home.php) so that only that page displays 100% in the main content section

```
    <div id="container">
        <div id="content" role="main">

        <?php
        /* Run the loop to output the page.
         * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
         * called loop-page.php and that will be used instead.
         */
        get_template_part( 'loop', 'page' );
        ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #container -->
```

The website is vistahomeimprovement.com

Answer (score 0):

As far as you are using home-page.php template only for main page, you can add class directly to container div and apply css rules to it:

```
<div id="container" class="on-main-page">...</div>
```

[image]

css:

```
#container.on-main-page {
 float: none;
 width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Did you look at the website?

Comment: Yes, I did. Your content div has 75% width and floats right. If you add logic I've posted, you can then add css rule like this: `#content.your-class-for-main-page { float: none; width: 100%; }`

Comment: If you could explain a bit further for me I apologize for my lack of knowledge on this subject. So do i add the logic you posted in the home page php template? Then add the ccs rule you posted into the main content section in the style.css?

Comment: Excuse me, I've just figured out, that you have separate template file (page-home.php), which, I assume, is used only for your home page. So you can add class directly without any "if" logic, because this template is not used elsewhere (or is it?).

Comment: Yes i have a page-home.php template just for the homepage not other pages.

Comment: <?php
/**
 * Template Name: Home
 */

get_header(); ?>

  <div id="container">
   <div id="content" role="main">

   <?php
   /* Run the loop to output the page.
    * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
    * called loop-page.php and that will be used instead.
    */
   get_template_part( 'loop', 'page' );
   ?>

   </div><!-- #content -->
  </div><!-- #container -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>

Comment: can you show me what to add into that above?

Comment: so you can just add some class to container div: `<div id="container" class="one-column on-main-page">...</div>` and css rule: `#container.on-main-page { float: none; width: 100%; }`

Comment: so add that class into the page-home php then add that css rule into syle.css main section?

Comment: yes, that's right

Comment: can you show exactly how it should look when i add that class into the page-home.php

Comment: edited my answer with screenshot

Comment: You have added class to the wrong div. It should be div with **ID** container, not **CLASS** container

Comment: Could you please mark my answer, it would be great